# Ruby Mocha expect the first argument to be a symbol

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-mocha

I'm trying to assert a method call happens where the first argument is a symbol like so:

`Foo.bar(:some_key, {})`

I don't really care what the second argument is at this stage.

I've tried:

`Foo.expects(:bar).with(includes(:some_key))`

and other variations found in the documentation [here](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html). The test passes when I expect the method call with any arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
Foo.expects(:bar).with(:some_key, anything)
```

If you need to be more specific you can also use a block :

```
Foo.expects(:bar).with do |first_arg, second_arg|
  first_arg == :some_key
end
```